# Converting dictionary into a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, regex

So, I've been tasked with converting a string into a dict (has to be using regex). I've done a findall to separate each element but not sure how to put it together.

I have the following code:

```py
import re

def edata():
  with open("employeedata.txt", "r") as file:
    employeedata = file.read()
    IP_field = re.findall(r"\d+[.]\d+[.]\d+[.]\d+", employeedata)
    username_field = re.findall (r"[a-z]+\d+|- -", employeedata)
    date_field = re.findall (r"\d+\/[A-Z][a-z][0-9]+\/\d\d\d\d:\d+:\d+:\d+ -\d+", employeedata)
    type_field = re.findall (r'"(.*)?"', employeedata)
    Fields = ["IP","username","date","type"]
    Fields2 = IP_field, username_field, date_field, type_field
    dictionary = dict(zip(Fields,Fields2))
    return dictionary

print(edata())
```

Current output:

```
{ "IP": ["190.912.120.151", "190.912.120.151"], "username": ["skynet10001", "skynet10001"] etc }
```

Expected output:

```
[{ "IP": "190.912.120.151", "username": "skynet10001" etc },
{ "IP": "190.912.120.151", "username": "skynet10001" etc }]
```

Comment: Can you share a sample of your inputs and the expected output?

Comment: Here's a row of data: 190.912.120.151 - skynet10001 [29/Jan/2012] "Temp" and teh desired output would be {
  "IP": "190.912.120.151",
  "username": "skynet10001" etc 

}

Comment: For the row of data you have given, how do you want your output dictionary to look like?

Comment: like I've written. { "IP": "190.912.120.151", "username": "skynet10001"} etc

Comment: Oops, did not refresh the page. Didn't see the updated comment. For the given input, this is the output I'm getting. Is this not what you are expecting?`{'IP': ['190.912.120.151'], 'username': ['skynet10001'], 'date': [], 'type': ['Temp']}`

Comment: Exactly correct yes. Do you know how to write this into the function I posted?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240079/discussion-between-kabilan-mohanraj-and-lysander2001).

Comment: OK, please send me a message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another solution that uses the dictionary that you have already constructed. This code uses list comprehension and the zip function to produce a list of dictionaries from the existing `dictionary` variable.

```
import re

def edata():
  with open("employeedata.txt", "r") as file:
    employeedata = file.read()
    IP_field = re.findall(r"\d+[.]\d+[.]\d+[.]\d+", employeedata)
    username_field = re.findall (r"[a-z]+\d+|- -", employeedata)

    date_field = re.findall (r"\[(.*?)\]", employeedata) ## changed your regex for the date field

    type_field = re.findall (r'"(.*)?"', employeedata)
    Fields = ["IP","username","date","type"]
    Fields2 = IP_field, username_field, date_field, type_field
    dictionary = dict(zip(Fields,Fields2))

    result_dictionary = [dict(zip(dictionary, i)) for i in zip(*dictionary.values())] ## convert to list of dictionaries
    return result_dictionary


print(edata())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```py
import re

rx = re.compile(r'^(?P<IP>\d+(?:\.\d+){3})\s+\S+\s+(?P<Username>[a-z]+\d+)\s+\[(?P<Date>[^][]+)]\s+"(?P<Type>[^"]*)"')

def edata():
    results = []
    with open("downloads/employeedata.txt", "r") as file:
        for line in file:
            match = rx.search(line)
            if match:
                results.append(match.groupdict())
    return results
    
print(edata())
```

See the [online Python demo](https://ideone.com/wPHy69). For the `file = ['190.912.120.151 - skynet10001 [19/Jan/2012] "Temp"', '221.143.119.260 - terminator002 [16/Feb/2021] "Temp 2"']` input, the output will be:

```
[{'IP': '190.912.120.151', 'Username': 'skynet10001', 'Date': '19/Jan/2012', 'Type': 'Temp'}, {'IP': '221.143.119.260', 'Username': 'terminator002', 'Date': '16/Feb/2021', 'Type': 'Temp 2'}]
```

The regex is

```py
^(?P<IP>\d+(?:\.\d+){3})\s+\S+\s+(?P<Username>[a-z]+\d+)\s+\[(?P<Date>[^][]+)]\s+"(?P<Type>[^"]*)"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/j4yGVo/2/). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?P<IP>\d+(?:\.\d+){3})` - Group "IP": one or more digits and then three occurrences of a `.` and one or more digits
- `\s+\S+\s+` - one or more non-whitespace chars enclosed with one or more whitespace chars on both ends
- `(?P<Username>[a-z]+\d+)` - Group "Username": one or more lowercase ASCII letters and then one or more digits
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `\[` - a `[` char
- `(?P<Date>[^][]+)` - Group "Date": one or more chars other than `[` and `]`
- `]\s+"` - a `]` char, one or more whitespaces, `"`
- `(?P<Type>[^"]*)` - Group "Type": zero or more chars other than `"`
- `"` - a `"` char.

Comment: Optimal solution!